# IIS Not Caching Images Between Visits

Tags: caching, iis

I'm trying cache static images in IIS. It's partially working - the images cache between requests when clicking through the site. But if I go to a different site (like google) then come back, I can see the images reloading again.

I'm not doing hard refresh, just pasting the url in the location bar and pressing [ENTER].

Here's my caching settings in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="5.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>
  ...
```

When I run `curl --head ...` on my image, here's what I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=432000
Content-Length: 10199
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Jan 2013 21:58:43 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "fbaa7c7a22f8cd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Set-Cookie: SessionId=14ab46aa-7633-412f-95c3-a3ce0667eb25; expires=Tue, 18-Apr-2113 16:17:54 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 16:17:54 GMT
```

I would expect the browser to read the cache until it expired. Any ideas why it's not using the cache?

Comment: Losing session or application pool restarting?

Comment: thanks @dirt, but no - i'm not losing session and the app pool isn't restarting

Comment: Do you have an authenticator installed?